# Structure for text message categorisation

Tags: nlp

I have a load of online chat messages and need to categorise them based on certain criteria, such as the topic, intention, tone of voice, type of information (e.g. dates & amounts), etc. Once categorised, these are used to train a model to automatically categorise new messages.

Currently, the categories (around 20) are a big hot mess that has been built up, ad-hoc, and doesn't have any particular structure to speak of.

My question is, what is a good approach to structuring the categories that would best capture the information and also be logical/orthogonal enough to train the model effectively.

Some stuff I've been considering: I've come across Searle's 5 types of "speech acts", which could be a useful way to differentiate messages at a more fundamental level than the particular business logic. What other models might be useful? Would a hierarchical structure make sense? Would it make sense to separate nouns, verbs, adjectives, and then drill down into specifics? What about "tagging" as opposed to a hierarchy to avoid similar nodes in different branches of the hierarchy. Any good resources to get started in this research?

Another approach I've looked into but haven't tried is a transformer-based clustering method where the centroids would then become the basis for categories.

If anyone has experience of doing this or just some thoughts, I'd be interested to hear!

Answer (score 0):

You can get an embedded vector for each sample, then do dimensionality reduction and then plot the samples in a 2D plane using the category as colour. This will give you something like this:

[image]

With that, you can start exploring the relationships among categories.

These are the details:

- To get embedded vectors, you can use the [sentence transformers library](https://www.sbert.net).
- To do dimensionality reduction, you can use [U-MAP](https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), as it is better than PCA and t-SNE.